# Kingo Root to uninstall

Tags: samsung, samsung-galaxy-j5

After rooted my phone with Kingo Root without pc, Does this be possibly be removed on the phone?

Comment: Does *what* be removed?  When?

Answer (score 1):

you mean remove root? of course you can.

1.download Kingo Root Android PC Version
2.Enable USB Debugging on your phone and connect you phone to PC.
3.There is a "Remove Root"  in Kingo.

it is easy.